# Surface area between two known 3D polynomials

Tags: calculus, 3d, surfaces, surface-integrals

I have two curves in 3D space with known equations of the form z = a*x + b*y.
[Curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/306AX.png)

I find the coefficients a and b with some simple Python scipy curve-fit code and the equations are well fitted. My calculus is pretty rusty. Is there a way to find the surface area between these two curves via integration?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe these two curves are parallel (so that this is an unambiguous way to tie a point on one curve to a point on the other curve)?  Also, if we dip your curves into soap solution and wave them around, the soap always gives a surface between them, but the surface area increases and decreases as we move it around.  Which area did you want?

Comment: @EricTowers I do have reason to believe these two curves are parallel (they will never intersect). The area I am looking for could best be represented by a thin-sheet stretched tightly between the two curves. So, the minimal surface area/representation between the two curves?

Comment: [Minimal surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface) are ... hard.  For more on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625316/minimal-surface-solution-in-python

Comment: Great! Thank you for the resources @EricTowers!